# Sections of $F \in \mathscr T$ (topos) on terminal object of $\mathscr T$

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a site, and $\mathscr T$ be its topos. $F \in \mathscr T, e$ the terminal object in $\mathscr T$.

We have the Yoneda embedding $T \mapsto \widetilde T = Hom(\cdot, T), T \in \mathscr C$, with a canonical identification $F(T) \cong Hom(T,F)$. In our case (crystalline site & topos), $\widetilde T$ is a sheaf.

According to "Notes on crystalline cohomology" -- Berthelot & Ogus, p. 5.15,

> a section $s \in \Gamma(e,F) = Hom(e,F)$ is just a compatible collection of sections $s_T \in F(T)$ for every $T \in \mathscr C$, i.e. an element of $\varprojlim_{T\in \mathscr C}F(T)$.

By definition, clearly an $s \in Hom(e,F)$ gives $s_T \in Hom(T,F) \forall T \in \mathscr C$. However, I am not sure about the opposite direction. Did I misunderstand the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Sorry about my earlier misreading. It is still true that the terminal object in any sheaf category represents the limit functor. The point is that an element of the limit of a sheaf $F$ is, by definition, a cone over $F$ tipped by the terminal set. To give such a cone is to give an element of each $F(T)$, compatible with transition maps $T\to T'$; but this is precisely the definition of a natural transformation from the terminal sheaf to $F$. In other words, a compatible family of elements of $x_T\in F(T)$ uniquely defines a map $e\to F$ sending the unique section of $e$ over $T$ to $x_T$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

However, in fact, $e$ is not even in $\mathscr C^{\mathrm{op}}$. :(

Setting $T=e$ seems obvious, except that $e$ is the terminal object of $\mathscr T$, while $T \in \mathscr C$. In the case of the crystalline topos, $e$ is not representable. I'd have no trouble if the inverse limit was over all $G \in \mathscr T$, clearly, since that includes $e$. But it's not...

Comment: What I take this to mean is not that some $s_e$ is equivalent to any $\{s_T\}$, but that $s_e$ can be recovered from the collection it yields.

Comment: I'm sorry about that! I read too quickly. I wasn't aware that algebraic geometers have important sites lacking a terminal object. Hopefully the rewrite works for you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand yet. I realize that the limit of the $F(T)$ gives a cone. What do you mean by "tipped by the terminal set"? Why is "this precisely the definition of a nat. transf. from $e$ to $F$"?

Comment: I mean it's a cone given by maps from the terminal set $e=e(T)$ to $F(T)$ for every $T$. It's the definition of a natural transformation because the commutative triangles defining a cone correspond to commutative squares defining a natural transformation, since $e(f)$ is an identity for every $f$ in $C$.